# what are the compilation flags that are activated by using O3

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, icc, compiler-flags

we are in the process of changing the intel compiler version from v14 to v18 in our systems and by running the tests, we have noticed that O3 in some cases produces incorrect results whereas the same code runs correctly with O3 and v14. I was wondering what are the differences in the optimizations between these two versions and how can I get a full list of flags that are getting activated by using O3 in each version. Thank you all in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: What flags were you using besides `O3`? Do your tests pass when you use `O2` with v18?

Comment: At last, some group that knows how to test!  I am impressed.  Congratulations.  Now, I suppose, It might be time for your team to review the requirements and identify why they think they need O3.  Perhaps your tests can confirm (or not) that less / lower optimization always avoids 'incorrect results', and if so, maybe the result is fast enough (while being correct).

Comment: Also, note that you can isolate the problematic results, for compilation at a lower / slower optimization level.  All the rest of the code can be fully optimized.   If your testing continues to work, this approach might be a reasonable first attempt to work around the issues you have found.

Comment: @Dai I have not checked with O2 but O0 is fine

Comment: @2785528 unfortunately, the timing difference is significant and non-optimized compilation is not accepted. Moreover, as I said v14 of O3 works perfectly fine and we do not have any issue. Since the code is used to solve a physical problem we can validate the final results and the instability problem with O3 v18 is not making any sense.

Comment: @2785528 Do you know how can I find the problematic part of the code quickly?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `-O3` is documented on Intel's website: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/optimization-options/o.html

> #### `O3`
>
> - Performs `O2` optimizations and enables more aggressive loop transformations such as Fusion, Block-Unroll-and-Jam, and collapsing IF statements.
> - This option may set other options. This is determined by the compiler, depending on which operating system and architecture you are using. The options that are set may change from release to release.
> - When O3 is used with options `-ax` or `-x` (Linux) or with options `/Qax` or `/Qx` (Windows), the compiler performs more aggressive data dependency analysis than for `O2`, which may result in longer compilation times.
> - The `O3` optimizations may not cause higher performance unless loop and memory access transformations take place. The optimizations may slow down code in some cases compared to O2 optimizations.
> - The `O3` option is recommended for applications that have loops that heavily use floating-point calculations and process large data sets.
> - Many routines in the shared libraries are more highly optimized for Intel® microprocessors than for non-Intel microprocessors.

The bottom of the page lists "Alternate options" which only lists `-Od` (which disables all optimizations: probably not what you want).

So it looks like `-O3` activates optimizations that cannot be represented by using other flags (so `-O3` does not have a long-form equivalent version).

[Looking at Intel's page about the techniques used for high-level optimization](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/optimization-and-programming-guide/high-level-optimization-hlo.html), it looks like they cannot be enabled *à la carte*, so with HLO it's all-or-nothing and is enabled using either `O2` or `O3` (except that `O2` uses a subset of `O3`'s techniques).

[Compare that to `-Ofast`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/optimization-options/ofast.html) which does have a long-form equivalent:

> #### `Ofast`
>
> - It sets compiler options `-O3`, `-no-prec-div`, and `-fp-model fast=2`.

Comment: Thank you for providing this part of the documentation. I have seen that but unfortunately, it doesn't mention explicitly what are the flags that are get activated with O3. I want to deactivate them one by one and find the flag that is causing the issue.

Comment: @user2348209 Please re-read my answer. The HLO enabled with `O3` are an all-or-nothing affair. There aren't any flags to selectively enable/disable those optimizations.

Comment: thank you for the comment, with all respect, I think what you said is not true. For example, just look at the following page from GNU GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html which clearly lists the flags that are getting activated with each level of optimization. I am looking for a similar list in intel compiler

Comment: With respect, but Intel isn’t GNU and the ICC isn’t GCC. There is nothing that requires compiler optimisations you be individually toggleable via the command-line. Given that the Intel compiler is supported by Intel you should contact them yourself via a support ticket to get an authoritative answer.